# Getting '\n' from string

Tags: c++, newline, getline

I have the text file called example.txt.

Its contents look something like this:

```
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \n hey my name \n is
```

I open this file and grab all the lines with `getline()`

```
int main() {
    string s;
    ifstream test;
    test.open("example.txt");
    getline(test,s);
    cout<<s;
}
```

Now I want to see this

```
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 hey my name
 is
```

But I see exactly what is in the text file.

Why does the `\n` symbol not move the cursor to the new line in this case?

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your text file contains separate `\` and `n` characters.  Unlike your C++ code, it's not pre-processed to turn those into newlines.

You'll need to either write real newlines into your file, or to replace every `"\\n"` with `"\n"` in your string `s` after you've read it.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` does not store as it on the file. Put your content in the new line in the text file. Or first, write the file using C++, then read. You need proper formatting to read it correctly.

`\n` is a symbol of a new line in the programming language. But it it is mentioned in the file it's a text content osaysay character. As \n stands for the new line so, if we save the file the `\n` is converted and saved as an actual new line in the text file.

Comment: \n is a symbol of a new line in the programming language. But it it is mentioned in the file it's a text content. As \n stands for the new line so, if we save the file the \n is converted and saved as an actual new line in the text file.

Comment: @RajatJain So there is any symbol I can put in the text file to make my program move the cursor to the new line? Or the way my think is wrong?

Comment: Just press ENTER and put the content to the new line. It will automatically be read as `\n`

Comment: @RajatJain I want take 1 line string and out it multi line

Comment: So, try removing the escape character ` \ ` from the read line.